# Delete Item in "Select Box" on State Change in React-Select (MultiSelect)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to delete items in **Select Box** as my state gets updated.
As of my current implementation, items gets deleted from the Options List Dropdown but the **Select Box** still shows that deleted value.

**The Setup**

[image]

**Curernt Behaviour**

Even after deleting item it still shows up in Select Box

[image]

**Goal**

Update Select Box as well on State Change.

Here's the [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-selected-item-on-state-update-in-react-select-5tib0?file=/src/styles.css)

Thanks in Advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **You will need to sync your updated option to your `Select` component too:**

You will need to use a new state and update them accordingly.

**So it's become:**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: "Text 1" },
    { id: 2, text: "Text 2" },
    { id: 3, text: "Text 3" }
  ]);

  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const deleteItem = (getID) => {
    setItems(items.filter((single) => single.id !== getID));
    setOptions(options.filter((single) => single.id !== getID));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ marginTop: 40, marginBottom: 40 }}>
        {items.map((data) => (
          <li>
            {data.text}
            <Button
              onClick={() => deleteItem(data.id)}
              color="primary"
              style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
            >
              Delete
            </Button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>

      <Select
        isMulti
        isSearchable
        maxMenuHeight={200}
        isClearable={false}
        options={items}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.text}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.text}
        value={options}
        onChange={(options) => setOptions(options)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Delete Selected Item on State Update in React-Select (forked)]

Comment: Hi Ryan, that isn't the way I believe as it sets default values as page loads and also if you uncheck items in Select Box it deletes them from state as well.

Comment: Ah, So you want to still be able to select options which already remove from the dropdown?

Comment: removed items from dropdown updates as state changes, but if I have selected an item in select box and I delete that item from parent state it does get the dropdown list updated the problem is that item still shows up in Select box, the issue is selected items in Select Box not being updated.

Comment: Hey @SikandarAliChishty, I updated my answer as well as the code sample, Hope it matches your needs.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Le, thank you for your response, this partially works. There are a few things here: 1. The options are still selected by default 2. when I deselect the options in checkbox and update state (delete item) it again fills the select box with remaining options.

Comment: Hey, Updated a few things, it should work perfectly now

Comment: Hi again @Ryan Le, just wondering if its possible to update values in as soon as state updates (in useEffect hook may be?) without delete button click?